# Why do I only get 1 output with model.predict() for an LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I am using LSTM to predict soil behaviour. I have generated 250 rows of data for one soil sample, and my LSTM model has 7 input and 3 output features (shapes of (1,250,7) and (1,250,3) respectively). I have compiled and fit my model with no problem, I understand that for `model.predict()` I need to have the same shape as the input (1,250,7). I have gathered the data together using `tf.concat()`, and when I tried to predict using that I have only gotten a single result.

How to correctly make predictions for the full 250 timesteps of data on a specific feature (such as the stress q)?

Whilst gathering the data using `tf.concat()` I have made all 7 features similar by converting the double tensor ones to a float tensor.

```
predict_tensor = tf.concat([dev_q_float, conf_p_expanded_float, void_e_expanded_float, dev_eps_expanded, dev_eps_change_expanded, dev_stress_change_expanded, conf_pres_change_expanded], axis=2)
```

Then when I applied

```
trainPredict = model.predict(predict_tensor)
print(trainPredict)
```

I have gotten this

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step
[[0.41100454]]
(1, 1)
```